# Finding workflow instance from a workflow step

Tags: java, workflow, aem

Doing a search of the source code, I found that a class, EmailWorkflow, which extends WorkflowProcess will need to be changed.

As I understand it, EmailWorkflow is a workflow step. How do I find all of the instances of a workflow that use this step so I can test them all after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search in /etc/workflow/models, nodes that contain a reference to the workflow process step (PROCESS property on a metadata node) will be part of a workflow model definition that will use that step.